# Cálculo de índice de massa corporal (IMC)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Meu código html é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WC3//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Aula 07</title>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aula07.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    img, table { width:165px; }
    fieldset { width:140px; }
    label { display:block; float:left;}
    label, input {width:68px; margin:3px 0; }
    th, td {border:1px solid #ccc; font-size:0.8em;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/imc.png" alt="imc"/>
    <form id="formulario">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Cálculo do IMC</legend>

            <label for="kilos">Quilos:</label>
            <input type="text" name="quilos"/>          

            <label for="metros">Metros:</label>
            <input type="text" name="metros"/>

            <label for="centimetros">Cm:</label>
            <input type="text" name="centimetros"/>

            <label for="imc">IMC:</label>
            <input type="text" name="imc" disabled="disabled"/>

            <a href="#" onclick="calcularIMC()">Calcular</a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

E o JavaScript é:

```
calcularIMC = function (){
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

var kilos = +formulario.kilos.value;    
var metros = +formulario.metros.value;  
var centimetros = +formulario.centimetros.value;

var altura = (metros*100 + centimetros)/100;    
var imc = kilos / (altura * altura);    
formulario.imc.value = imc.toFixed(2);
}
```

Ao usar o Notepad++, a página HTML parece não estar "chamando" o JavaScript, fazendo com que nenhum resultado apareça no campo IMC.
Grato a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Verifica se o teu `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aula07.js"></script>` tem o caminho correto para o ficheiro que contem o calculo do IMC

Comment: Uma boa forma de veres se o ficheiro js esta a ser carregado correctamente, é ires ver o código fonte da página (Ver fonte da página) e clicas no `src="js/aula07.js"`. Se abrir uma aba no teu browser com o teu documento js é porque está a carregar bem

Comment: Amigo, seu código está funcionando, veja ele em funcionamento [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/6ZSUm/), deve ser o caminho do script: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aula07.js"></script>` que está incorreto como citou @CesarMiguel. Verifique o caminho.

Comment: O seu script tem só o que colocou aqui ou tem mais código?

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal, consegui resolver.

Comment: @sscarvalho a resposta aceite é a solução do problema? Se não fôr pode responder você. Assim fica mais util para quem vir esta pergunta e tenha problema semelhante.

Comment: Não tem muito a ver com a dúvida, só vou comentar com [esse link](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/HP6W7/) porque sua fórmula de IMC ficou bem estranha pra mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o script é carregado corretamente. Porém, se você abrir o console do seu browser (atalho: F12 na maior parte deles), verá que ocorre um erro de execução, que previne sua função de terminar de executar.

Com o console aberto, experimente clicar no botão calcular, e terá pistas de onde seu erro se encontra.

Apenas para esclarecer, é necessário trocar:

```
var kilos = +formulario.kilos.value;
```

Por:

```
var kilos = +formulario.quilos.value;
```

Espero que ajude! Abraços!

Comment: E (não relacionado ao erro) é necessário corrigir os "for" dos labels! Eles sempre se referem a IDs, e não names!

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Rui Pimentel, mas não foi preciso excluir os "+", apenas trocar "kilos" por "quilos". Quanto ao "for", ainda estou muito "cru" para entender esses detalhes rsrs

Comment: Por nada! Interessante isso aí do +, pra que você usa? :) Nunca vi! E quanto aos "for", labels servem basicamente para aumentar a área de click que leva ao elemento especificado (via ID, no "for"). Names servem apenas para este tipo de navegação em forms que você fez no JavaScript, e também para recuperação dos campos lá no lado servidor; todos os parâmetros da requisição HTTP são identificados pelos names, e não pelos IDs! :)

Comment: o "+" faz cast do valor para número.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo :D alterei a resposta, pra ficar mais próxima do que o OP queria, então.

Comment: Estou seguindo um passo a passo de um vídeo, e nele está dito para colocar esse "+", mas não me lembro a razão nem se isso foi informado. Infelizmente ainda não cheguei ao nível de criticar meu aprendizado, estou apenas "engolindo os conceitos" rsrs

Comment: Ah, só agora que vi, @Moykn, é isso mesmo, obrigado!