# Cálculo de IMC automático em INPUT

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas com esse codigo, quando eu realizo ela dá um resultado errado e não consigo limitar casa decimais.

```js
function calcular() {
  var peso = parseInt(document.getElementById('peso').value);
  var alt = parseInt(document.getElementById('alt').value);
  document.getElementById('imc').innerHTML = peso / Math.pow(alt, 2);
}
```

```html
 <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputPeso"> <h6><strong>Peso</strong></h6> </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="peso" name="peso" placeholder="Insira Peso (kg)" onfocus="calcular()">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputAddress2"><h6><strong>Altura</strong></h6></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alt" name="alt" placeholder="Insira Altura (m)" onblur="calcular()">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="inputAddress2"><h6><strong>IMC</strong></h6></label>
   <div type="text" class="form-control" id="imc" name="imc"></div>
  </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Cálculo de índice de massa corporal (IMC)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27440/c%c3%a1lculo-de-%c3%adndice-de-massa-corporal-imc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente eu fiz algumas correções no seu seu código principalmente em JavaScript.

No seu html eu apenas alterei o onfocus e onblur para onkeyup porque pelo que entendi e análise pelo código você quer que cada número que o usuário digitar seja feito o cálculo do imc e para isso é necessário o [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeyup.asp) e também alterei o tipo do input para number.

O código JavaScript abaixo esta todo comentado e o HTML tem as alterações.

#### JavaScript

```
/**
* Sugestao(oes):
*  - Verificar se o usuario digitou a altura
*    realmente em metros.
*/

function calcular() {
  // Pega o valor do peso.
  var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;

  // Verifica se o simbolo de casas decimais e
  // o do Brasil.
  if (peso.indexOf(",") > -1) {
    // Se sim ,corrige para o padrao americano
    // e programavel.
    peso.replace("," ,".");

  // Verifica se o valor de 'peso' nao esta vasio.
  } else if (!(peso)) {
    // Se sim ,define para o valor para 1.
    peso = 1;
  }

  // Converte 'peso' para numero decimal.
  peso = parseFloat(peso);

  // Verifica se 'peso' e igual a zero.
  if (peso == 0) {
    // Se sim ,define 'peso' como 1.
    peso = 1;
  }

  // Pega o valor da altura.
  var alt = document.getElementById('alt').value;

  // Verifica se o simbolo de casas decimais e
  // o do Brasil.
  if (alt.indexOf(",") > -1) {
    // Se sim ,corrige para o padrao americano
    // e programavel.
    alt.replace("," ,".");

  // Verifica se o valor de 'alt' nao esta
  // vasio.
  } else if (!(alt)) {
    // Se sim ,define para o valor para 1.
    alt = 1;
  }

  // Converte 'alt' para numero decimal.
  alt = parseFloat(alt);

  // Verifica se 'alt' e igual a zero.
  if (alt == 0) {
    // Se sim ,define 'alt' como 1.
    alt = 1;
  }

  // Cacula e exibe o imc ao usuario.
  document.getElementById('imc').innerHTML = (peso / Math.pow(alt, 2)).toFixed(2);
}
```

#### HTML - Form

```
<!-- Mudancas
  Substituicao dos eventos 'onfocus' e 'onblur' pelo evento 'onkeyup'.
  Substituicao do typo de entra de 'text' para 'number'
-->

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputPeso"> <h6><strong>Peso</strong></h6> </label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="peso" name="peso" placeholder="Insira Peso (kg)" onkeyup="calcular()">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputAddress2"><h6><strong>Altura</strong></h6></label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="alt" name="alt" placeholder="Insira Altura (m)" onkeyup="calcular()">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputAddress2"><h6><strong>IMC</strong></h6></label>
      <div type="text" class="form-control" id="imc" name="imc"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Muitooo obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente...... valeu mesmo amigo!!

Comment: Muito por nada.

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer (remova o parseInt)

```
 function calcular() {
  var peso = 68.00;
  var alt = 1.0; 
  var imc = parseFloat( peso / Math.pow(alt, 2)).toFixed(2);


  alert(imc)


} 

calcular();
```

Comment: Não funcionou !

Comment: você tem que remover o ParseInt()